# Problems with shear force diagram in beam model

Tags: beam, ansys, diagram

I am starting to learn how to use ANSYS APDL. So I don't have much knowledge in the software.

I have modelled a cantilever beam (with beam188 elements) and the only load that i have applied was the self weight.

When I ask for the shear force diagram (element table) and plot the results, the SFD looks like this:

[image]

Shouldn't it be linear? What happened?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the units of stress as displayed? The min is -19600, but what units?

Comment: -19600 is the shear force in Newtons!

Comment: Yes, it should be linear. It's hard to troubleshoot an FE model with a single image though. I'd suggest that you check all boundary conditions, maybe you've accidentally restrained some nodes? if you find nothing, maybe try to rebuild the model in a new file from scratch and see what you get.

Comment: I second @WilliamS.Godfrey-S.E. , some DOFs seem missing. Try to plot the deformed structure, and also post the APDL script here, it should only be few lines of code

Answer (score -1):

Dear madam ,
             pls make beam with keypoints and then do meshing with mesh tool and use smisc3 and 16 for bending moment and smisc 6 & 19 for shear force